# How to pass one column of data as a list using viewbag to a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, viewbag

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to pass one column of data in a list using viewbag to a strongly typed view. I am passing a list of CustomerSites using a strongly typed view. I would also like to display a CustomerName next to each CustomerSite in the list.

I have tried the following approach, but as the controller is returning a list of customers it wont let me access the CustomerName property from the view, is it possible to access this property from the view?

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var q = from a in db.Customers.ToList()
        select a;
        ViewBag.customer = q;
        return View(db.CustomerSites.ToList());
    }

@model IEnumerable<trsDatabase.Models.CustomerSite>
@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
<tr>
 <td>
        @ViewBag.customer.CustomerName
   </td>
   <td>
        @customer.UnitNo
    </td>
    <td>
        @Truncate(customer.StreetName, 25)
    </td>
    <td>
        @customer.Town
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=customer.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=customer.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=customer.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: why did you ask the same question 2 times while the first hast a correct answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910767/returning-a-list-to-strongly-typed-view-using-viewbag

Comment: @DanielB Because although yes the answer was correct, it did not provide an answer to the problem, and i still havent been able to resolve the issue

Comment: Look at my answer. you have to select a single customer you want by specifying a where clause. wich customer you would like to display? a specific one? so you have to select the one.

Comment: @DanielB i want to display all the customer names for every customer address that's included in the list, so i have a list of customer sites being generated in the view from one DB table, then i want a list of the corresponding names for each site that are in another db table, so in effect two lists.

Comment: @DanielB really its one list made up from two Database objects.

Comment: @liam watson but you want to display only one of them, the you have to get one from your list.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to pass to the View a ViewModel built out from CustomerSites and CustomerNames. Why don't you get from the DB object which consists from Customer name and site?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `ViewBag.customer` holds a collection of `Customers` not a single `Customer` object. In your Query you should have a `where` part.